# JPA Subquery not working

Tags: java, sql, jpa, subquery

I am trying to execute a JPA Query.

```
select c from Chats c where c.userAndroidId=:userAndroidId and c.companyId = :companyId and c.id >= (select min(c2.id) from Chats c2 where c2.status=1 and c2.companyId = :companyId 
and c2.userAndroidId= :userAndroidId) union all 
(select c3 from chats c3 where c3.userAndroidId=:userAndroidId and c3.companyId = :companyId and c3.id < (select min(c4.id) from Chats c4 where c4.status=1 and c4.companyId = :companyId and c4.userAndroidId=:userAndroidId) order by c3.id desc limit 2) order by c.id desc;
```

As per my understanding, it has two variables, `userAndroidId` and `companyId`.

I get an error

> Not all named parameters have been set: [id] [Select c from Chats c
>   where c.userAndroidId = :userAndroidId and c.companyId = :companyId
>   and id > :id order by id desc]

Comment: Clean out your target directories and rebuild your project.  The code you're running is NOT the code you exhibited here.

Comment: and JPQL does not have such a thing as "UNION ALL". The JPA spec is easily findable on the web